# Twitter Finagle client: How to make external REST api call?

Tags: scala, rest, finagle, twitter-finagle

I'm trying to make an external (to finagle server) REST GET request in my finagle code, the URI for is: http://service.site-dev.com/subservices/list

I'm using the client code found in the example at : https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/finagle.html#client

My code (written in Scala) looks like the following, but the it just hangs even though I set a timeout limit:

```
val client: Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] = ClientBuilder()
  .codec(Http())
  .hosts("http://service.site-dev.com") // If >1 host, client does simple load-balancing
  .hostConnectionLimit(1)
  .tcpConnectTimeout(1.second)
  .requestTimeout(20.seconds)
  .retries(2)
  .build()

val req = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "http://service.site-dev.com/subservices/list")

val f = client(req) // Client, send the request

// Handle the response:
f onSuccess { res =>
  println("got response", res)
} onFailure { exc =>
  println("failed :-(", exc)
}
```

I suspect my hosts param is wrong? But what am I suppose to put in there is this is an call  to an external REST service?

Comment: you should use Future.Await so that your main thread doesn't die or finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string argument to `hosts` isn't a URI, but instead should have the form `"host:port"` (or `"host1:port1,host2:port"` for a set of hosts), so changing that line to `.hosts("service.site-dev.com:80")` should fix the issue.

I'm a little surprised that you're not seeing a `NumberFormatException`—what version of Finagle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this
https://github.com/opower/finagle-resteasy

It's a drop-in Finagle-based replacement for Resteasy's client executor.